# Organic groups and "Create content"

Tags: organic-groups

I want to replicate the Drupal "Create Poll,Event" links etc of the Drupal groups.
How can I accomplish that with Organic groups?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean in the sidebar of groups.drupal.org?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using a custom block with format as php option. You need to use [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to generate links.

```
$links = "";
$linkList .= l(t('Create Poll'), 'node/add/poll', array('html' => TRUE, 'query' => array('gid[]' => arg(1))));
$linkList .= l(t('Create Event'), 'node/add/event', array('html' => TRUE, 'query' => array('gid[]' => arg(1))));
print $links;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use panels, Organic Groups module comes with a content create panel pane that allows to select the content types to include in such a links list.